# Nested conditions in python

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out the shortest, most pythonic way to implement a similar to the following syntax:

```
if A and (B if C):
    print(A)
```

in a way that:

- if C is False, then `B` is omitted (therefore `(B if C)` is True).
- if C is True, then B is evaluated, effectively making the syntax *`if A and B:`*

This can be made through various separate `if` statements, but my ultimate purpose with this was to make it into a list comprehension for a value assignment.

Edit:

The list comprehension I wanted to make was this:

```
methods = [name for (name, func) in locals().items() \
    if callable(func) and (not __name__ == '__main__' or \
    func.__module__ == __name__)]
```

So that it returns the function names I have defined in that module as well as if `methods` is imported from the outside.

Comment: @chepner Right, thanks, it's not as simple.

Comment: `if A and (B if C else True):` or `(A and B) if C else A:`

Comment: If C is False, then the statement has to be true if A is true. But I admit I hadn't thought of that. @coldpseed Sorry for the late response, I see it was already responded...

Comment: `A, B = True and C = False -> True` and `A,B,C = True -> True` right? If so then it would be `if A and not C or B:`

Comment: @MarioG.C. you say "my ultimate purpose with this was to make it into a list comprehension for a value assignment".  Perhaps you'd like to post an example of the list comprehension you had in mind?  The key here is that Python uses lazy evaluation so `if A and C and B:` works because if C is False it would not evaluate B and vice versa.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh the first option that you said, `if A and (B if C else True)` does what I said and works perfectly inside my list comprehension. Post it as an answer if you want :)

Comment: glad to hear @MarioG.C. You can give the correct answer to one of the ones below, i dont mind. :)

Comment: Thank you everybody, it turned out to be a very interesting question. I wish I could accept every correct answer, but I will choose the most upvoted one since it seems to be the oldest one that also has the furthest explanation.

Comment: @RonKalian I see, but if C is False and A is True it would have to run anyway.

Comment: @MarioG.C.If C is False and A is True, then with `if A and C and B` A runs, C also runs, but as it is False, the whole condition evaluates to False and B is not run.  If A is True, and C is True, then B is run.

Comment: @RonKalian Ah, I get what you're trying to say, but I meant that I still needed the "print" that I showed in my pseudocode, it's not just about evaluating the expressions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be equivalent, if my old statement logic doesn't fail me =)

```
if A and (not C or B):
    print(A)
```

Explanation: `"B if C" <=> C -> B <=> not C or B`

Expression `B` is only evaluated if `C` holds.

Answer (score 2):

your hypothesis:

- if C is False, then B is omitted
- if C is True, then B is evaluated, effectively making the syntax if A and B:

wouldn't that be:

```
if A and (not C or B):
    print(A)
```

- if `C` is false then `not C` is `True` and we don't evaluate `B`
- if `C` is true, then `not C` is `False`, and we have to evaluate `B`

Answer (score 2):

Your `if` pseudo-operator is just logical implication, where

```
C -> B = not C or B
```

This means you just want

```
if A and (not C or B):
```

When `C` is False, `A and (not C or B) == A and (True or B) == A and True == A`.

When `C` is True, `A and (not C or B) == A and (False or B) == A and B`.

Comment: Fun, irrelevant fact: some languages actually *have* logical implication. In Nix, for example, you could actually write `A && (C -> B)` as a Boolean expression instead of `A && (!C || B)`. Whether that is more readable depends on how grounded you are in logic :)

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
if A and (B if C else True):
    pass
```

is closest to your "pseudo code", using the conditional expression `x if cond else y` in Python. Assuming `B=True` in case `C` is `False` effectively make the `if` statement consider only the boolean value of `A`

Comment: I think this would actually be my preferred way to write it in Python.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably write it like this:

```
condition = (A and B) if C else A
if condition:
    print(A)
```

I've only broken the condition into a separate variable because I think mixing an `if` with a Python conditional expression looks a little confusing. You'll have to make a call whether it looks confusing when used inside a list comprehension or not.